# Norway location for vacation with Lakes and fields but no people?

Tags: norway, vacations, lakes

I'm looking for places to spend my vacation in Norway but I want something like a field empty with no people no cities, no cars, just silence and a lake.

I don't want mountain trips or to live inside a tent, I'm looking for a small house to rent and stay near a lake

Something like this:

[image]

Basically no people arround, that's what I want, total silence and peace.

So far I was checking visitnorway.com and I've seen many big cities on their map beautiful ones but they are all with people, so is not really what I am looking for.

Any help? Thank you!

Comment: What season are we talking about here? The lovely image suggests winter.

Comment: What happened to the Netherlands?

Comment: @GayotFow September-Octomber (Fall)

Comment: @ByronSchmuland well.. It seems that norway has much more to offer.

Comment: Would you accept a self-catered cottage holiday on the "Island of Silence" in Hammerfest? It's on a fjord rather than a lake.